# How to make alias expand upon expression evaluation only?

Tags: windbg

Suppose I set a breakpoint, that sets another breakpoint that is supposed to trace code execution. It looks like:

```
bp module!function "as /x {/v:alName} expr;ba w1 @@c++(expr) \".if(${alName}) {actions}\""
```

How do I make ${alName} evaluate at "ba" breakpoint hit? BTW I tried to enclose "ba" into .block statement right inside "bp" breakpoint command list, but this doesn't work for me either. If I put "bp" command list into a separate file and set "bp" to `"$$><scriptName"` - works ok. But this sort of "bp" I have here is already specified in another script file.

Comment: Try enclosing the if statement in a `.block{}` statement. See "Using Aliases" in the debugger help, specifically where it states, "The problem is that myAlias is not expanded until a new block of code is entered." and "We can fix this problem by enclosing the .echo (Echo Comment) command in a new block as shown in the following script."

Comment: @MarcSherman I tried to do so, but the alias eventually gets substituted as if no .block statement is in use. I use a workaround - place the breakpoint action script in a separate script file and: bp module!function "$$><script". This solves the problem but I wanted to find out how to achieve the same without a separate script since this command is already in a script file.

Comment: Hey, at least you managed to escape the quotation marks. Seriously: the WinDbg scripting language has a few issues. Can't you use a real scripting language such as PyKD?

Comment: @ThomasWeller I need to try it out...